# WPF brush displays negative elements on canvas

Tags: wpf, vb.net, canvas

I'm making a drag and drop application and when I'm dragging an element inside the canvas the brush displays the element when the coordinates are negative this gives a weird resize in the brush witch also displays the negative elements.
How can I make the visual brush only draw the real size of the canvas, or the positive children of the canvas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The view port always shows the items with negative values too. I did not want this effect in my brush so i had to find another solution.

```
    myBrush.Visual = TheCanvas
    Dim _viewRect As Rect
    Private _viewGeo As RectangleGeometry
```

Each time the canvas size changes I call this method so when I have negative members being dragged in it doesn't show it on the brush. Do not call this method on startup because you're canvas width and height won't have values.

```
    _viewRect = New Rect(0, 0, TheCanvas.Width, TheCanvas.Height)
    _viewGeo  = New RectangleGeometry(_viewRect)
    TheCanvas.Clip = _viewGeo
```